# Call function by variable string name and variable parameter

Tags: java, android, function, methods, reflection

Scenario: I have a list of functions, example :

```
function1(int a, int b)
function2(String a)
function3(String a, String a)
...
```

I need to be able to select and call a function by a string while also having different parameters.

```
String functionName = "function1"
```

or

```
String functionName = "function2"
```

and then 
`callFunction(functionName) - (somehow adding parameters too`)

I can do this with using:

```
if(functionName == "function1"){
function1(int a, int b);
}else if(functionName == "function2"){
function2(String a)
}...
```

But this doesn't seem efficient when I have a long list of functions.

I have tried using reflection:

```
String methodName = "thisMethod";
        Method newMethod = null;
        try {
            newMethod = FormActions.class.getMethod(methodName, String.class);
        } catch (e) {}
        try {
            newMethod.invoke(this, "THIS IS A STRING");
        } catch (e) {}
```

which is good because I can call:

```
public void thisMethod(String text ){
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

however if methodName was set to "otherMethod" which takes a int = otherMethod(int a)

Then this would no longer work.

Is there a good way to doing this or should I use the first if-else/switch method.

Comment: google for 'java introspection' for further information, and read the SO question that @Vlad linked.

Comment: If I have to search through all methods and check if they are compatible with the parameters then I might as well use the first if-else / switch method to check the names of functions instead. Correct?